Автозапуск нескольких файлов python
За время работы накопилось много файлов, которые я обновляю каждый день. На данный момент использую jupyter notebook. Но собираюсь все конвертировать в файлы с расширением .py для того, чтобы можно было автоматически их запускать.
В процессе изучения способов для решения данной задачи, я нашла несколько вариантов:

Apache Airflow - но как я поняла, он больше подходит для больших решений, с множеством файлов, и достаточно сложен для установки
Библиотека schedule - как писали на одном из форумов, это решение больше подходит для сиюминутных задач, то есть когда надо запускать каждые 5 минут или каждый час. Там есть функция для запуска кода каждый день, но для этого нужно, чтобы код постоянно был запущен
Библиотека cron - более подходящее решение, и более универсальное

Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться с выбором инструмента. Он должен удовлетворять нескольким условиям:

Есть ли такой инструмент, который будет обновлять файлы при выключенном компьютере
Где должны храниться питоновские файлы, которые нужно запускать по расписанию и связанные с ними файлы, которые будут обновляться
У меня есть код с библиотекой selenium, который не всегда отрабатывает с 1 раза, иногда требуется перезапускать его раз 5-8 (иногда очень долго прогружается сайт, иногда работает все быстро), как быть в такой ситуации, чтобы не было остановки кода
Как можно сделать оповещения о том, что код успешно обновлен?

Интересует решение для mac и windows


При выключенном компьютере в принципе ничего не может работать =)
Остановку кода можно легко избежать, достаточно обрабатывать исключения, так же на случай долгой загрузки сайта, selenium обычно предоставляет что-то вроде OnLoad метода, который проверяет загрузилась ли страница

